# JSON column formatting - Format date column to remove minutes using in an IF statement?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to format a column that reacts to a value from another column, one of the columns "Projected End Date" is a date format.  This has the column formatting applied and when an adjacent column "Project Overrunning" changes to "Overrun" I am changing the value within the "Projected End Date" column to "Overrunning".

This part I've got working but the issue is that the date in the "Projected End Date" is formatted DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM:SS and I'd like to remove the HH:MM:SS.  In the past I usually do this by just changing `txtContent` to "@currentField" and this strips the minutes away, but it appears when I use this in a IF statement it doesn't work.

I've tried to use `toLocaleDateString()` but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Minutes showing:

[image]

Value changed to "Overrunning":

[image]

This is how far I've got:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "[$Project_x0020_Overruning]",
            "Overrun"
          ]
        },
        "sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground50",
        ""
      ]
    }
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "line-height": "16px",
        "height": "14px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Project_x0020_Overruning]",
                "Overrun"
              ]
            },
            "",
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px"
      },
      "txtContent": "=if([$Project_x0020_Overruning] == 'Overrun', 'Overrunning', '@currentField')",
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Project_x0020_Overruning]",
                "Overrun"
              ]
            },
            "",
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: Try my answer given below and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
"txtContent": "=if([$Project_x0020_Overruning] == 'Overrun', 'Overrunning', toLocaleDateString(@currentField))"
```

> **toLocaleDateString()**: returns a language sensitive representation of just the date portion of a date.
>
> - `"txtContent":"=toLocaleDateString(@now)"` results vary based on user's locale, but en-us looks like "2/5/2019".

**Reference**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint - Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#operators)

Comment: Also, I see you have added on span children with blank iconName and class attribute in last children element. If that is intentional then it is fine. But, if you want to remove it and want to optimize the code then let me know. I will update the answer with optimized code by removing the empty attribute code.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, that worked perfectly, strange as I am sure I tried that...but obviously didn't :)  I am using the code that SharePoint produces as my template so any advice on making this better would be great.

Comment: Possibly be cautious of using `toLocaleDateString()`.  In my experience, if the list item date value is entered as `01/01/21`, when I use `toLocaleDateString()` in column formatting, it displays on the list as `31/12/2020` (ie it is one day off the date entered).  I am currently trying to resolve the issue here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/68360532

Answer (score 0):

You could just try to change to column setting.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The column formatting overrides this setting